# How to make a unit test for upload img? React testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Have a problem to simulate uploading the image file via unit testing with Jest and testing library in react.

This is my JSX / component part of the code:

```
 <ChangeImgForm>
        <Image img={uploadedImg || avatarImg} alt="User profile" />

        <ButtonsContainer>
          <UploadBtn>
            <FileUploadBtn
              handleFile={handleUploadFile}
              allowExtensions=".png,.jpeg,.webp"
            />
          </UploadBtn>
          <RemoveBtn>
            <Button>Remove</Button>
          </RemoveBtn>
        </ButtonsContainer>
      </ChangeImgForm>
```

This is a UNIT test that I am trying to make work:

```
test("Select an image and upload will make a request to upload it", () => {
  const { container, getByLabelText, getByText, getByAltText } = render(
    <Settings />
  );
  const file = new File(["dummy content"], "example.png", {
    type: "image/png",
  });
  const uploadBtn = screen.getByTestId("uploadBtn");
  const inputFile = screen.getByTestId("inputFile");
  fireEvent.change(inputFile, { target: { files: [file] } });

  inputFile.files = [file];
  fireEvent.change(inputFile);

  expect(inputFile.files).toBe(file);
});
```

Any comment is welcome

Comment: What is the exact problem? It would be good to see if you are referring to a specific error message. The reason being, it's also hard for people to verify these things locally and then answer. So please do provide more info. :)

Comment: Hey @NagarajTantri, I am try to upload file and check does it uploaded. 
I also wanted to send that on server, but it's not that important. 
Upload and check of upload will be great :)

Comment: You should create a minimal, reproducible example, we don't know what `ChangeImgForm`, `ButtonsContainer`, and `Image` components look like. It's hard to tell the reason

Comment: @slideshowp2 I updated the test, now should be closer to the solution